# Replacing multiple string value in a list Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list like  `list = ['happy', 'angry', 'sad', 'emotion']`.

So I want to replace the list and make new list like

```
new_list=[1, 0, 0, 'happy']
```

following is the my code and it does not work.

```
if emotion=='happy':
list .replace('happy', '1').replace('angry', '0').replace('sad', '0').replace('emotion', 'happy')
```

what would be the correct way of doing this. Please help me !

Comment: I'm not sure the dupe quite covers it, here's my answer anyway....replace is a string attribute, not for lists. I suggest use use a dictionary with a list comprehension to map your new values to the old ones:

    `d = {'happy':1, 'angry':0, 'sad':0, 'emotion':'happy'};
    [d.get(item,item) for item in lst];
    # [1, 0, 0, 'happy'];`

Comment: You say your expected output is `[1, 0, 0,'happy']`, but then you replace the words with _strings_, not with numbers (`.replace('happy', '1')`). So is the result supposed to have integers or strings?

Comment: You need to think about your logic and look to make it more generic. It looks like you are trying to replace the matching emotion with 1 and all others with 0 (unless it is the word `'emotion'` then replace with `emotion`, you can do this with a comprehension: `[1 if e == emotion else emotion if e == 'emotion' else 0 for e in lst]` -> `[1, 0, 0, 'happy']`

Comment: I'm not sure that the dupe covers this, this maybe an XY problem.

Comment: Duplicate is not true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = ['happy','angry','sad','emotion']
new_list = [int(y) if y.isdigit() else y for y in [x.replace('happy', '1').replace('angry', '0').replace('sad', '0').replace('emotion', 'happy') for x in list]]
```

If you want to replace more than these 4 values, it would make sense to make a generalized replace-function which takes several replacements, e.g. two lists.

**EDIT**: Fixed in case you absolutely want numbers and not strings as output

Comment: This is not work.

Comment: @Chathurika Jayawardana Fixed for you

Comment: Now its work as I expected. Thank you for the answer.